# Noticed a context property being passed to webpack along with my configuration. Where does it come from?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to understand how the internals of webpack work in order to contribute in the future. I noticed that when running webpack the `webpack` function in `/lib/webpack.js` fires with an `options` argument.

The value of this argument is my configuration object defined in `webpack.config.js` PLUS a `context` property that I never defined. Where does this `context` property come from? Is there a step that occurs before the `webpack` function fires?

Comment: `WebpackOptionsDefaulter`

Comment: Seems that I'm assuming the wrong starting point. Looks like I should be looking at `/bin/webpack.js`, not `/lib/webpack.js`. Inside the former is the function `processOptions` which seems to be adding the `context` property.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack needs to know where to start looking for files, which you will reference in either your Webpack config file or your JS source files that will be processed by Webpack.

By default, it reverts to the current working directory of where the CLI was used -- commonly the same directory where your Webpack config file exists -- however, you should always define this manually using the `context` key in your Webpack Config file (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx).

Webpack also uses this directory path (absolute path) as the prefix for any [module resolution / aliasing](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) used throughout in your source files, etc.

Comment: Right. I understand that. I'm asking this question from the perspective of someone who is reading / trying to understand the webpack source code. I noticed that there is an options object with a value equal to my configuration PLUS the context property, which i never explicitly defined. This led me to believe that there was another step before the one I was assuming was the first step.